# Universal point sets for 1-plane graphs

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-geometry, plane-geometry, graph-drawing

It is a notorious open problem to find a smallest set of $N$ points that
permit any $n$-vertex planar graph to be drawn in the plane without
crossings, using only those $N$ points as vertices, and straight segments
as edges. An upperbound of $O(n^2)$
is provided by integer grids, but the best lowerbound is linear in $n$.
A point set that allows such plane drawings for every $n$-vertex planar 
graph is called a *universal set*.

My question is:

> ***Q***. Are there subquadratic universal sets for drawing $1$-plane graphs,
>   graphs that have a straight-line drawing where each edge is crossed by at most
>   one other edge? If this is not known, are there subquadratic universal sets for drawing $k$-plane graphs, for some $k > 1$?

As $k$ approaches $n$, there should be linear-size universal sets.

---

[image]

          

<sup>Fig.1: Chaplick, Steven, Fabian Lipp, Alexander Wolff, and Johannes Zink.</sup>


          

<sup>"Compact Drawings of 1-Planar Graphs with Right-Angle Crossings and Few Bends." [arXiv:1806.10044](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.10044) (2018).</sup>

---

Comment: [1-planar graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1-planar_graph) have a drawing---not necessarily with straight edges---where each edge is crossed by at most one other edge. I'm using "1-plane graphs" to also require straight edges.

Comment: Is the question asking about universal sets for 1-plane drawings of *planar* graphs?